# Why does my accept rating get affected If a question was migrated to another server?

Tags: support, migration, accept-rate

I had a question that I created on Stack Overflow, it was moved to Super User before any answers were created and I accepted the answer on Super User, though Stack Overflow sees this as an unanswered question and inherintly it affects my accept rating.

Is this a bug or is this intentional?

Comment: Karma for offending the "belongs-on-x" gods!

Comment: @beggs, lol, to tell you the truth I am reasonably new to SO and it was actually a question I posted before I even knew superuser.com existed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updating the accept rate delays heavily! Wait one or two days.

Comment: Ahh, thank you very much John, much appreciated.